# Is there any recommended compileSdkVersion for each Google Play Services SDK version?

Tags: android, google-play-services

As the topic suggested, as I try to update the version of Google Play Services SDK used in my app (from `5.0.89` to `9.2.0`):

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
```

A large batch of errors like the one below occur:

```
> .../app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v21/values-v21.xml
> 
> Error:(13) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
> matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
> 
> Error:(15) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
> matches the given name
> 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
> 
> ...

And:
> .../com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.0.0/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml
> 
> Error:(82, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr
> 'android:colorAccent'.

> Error:(82, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
> ...
```

Which I happens to fix them by raising the `compileSdkVersion` of my project. Then I tried to selectively compile only the SDKs I needed in my project, i.e.:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.0'
```

With this setting I was able to keep my original `compileSdkVersion`, which is `19`, and build and (seem to?) run the application without problem.

However, this left me wondering if there will be any potential problem as there is such a significant update regarding those SDKs. And this raised the question as suggested in the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Picking your compileSdkVersion, minSdkVerison, and targetSdkVersion blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd):

> It should be emphasized that changing your compileSdkVersion **does not change runtime behavior.**
>
> Therefore it is **strongly recommended that you always compile with the latest SDK.** You’ll get all the benefits of new compilation checks on existing code, avoid newly deprecated APIs, and be ready to use new APIs.
>
> Note that if you use the Support Library, compiling with the latest SDK is a requirement for using the latest Support Library releases. **For example, to use the 23.1.1 Support Library, you must have a compileSdkVersion of at least 23** (those first numbers need to match!).

So just always use the latest version for compileSdkVersion